# Fetching the Zookeeper url and the Solr collection name from within a Solr component code

Tags: java, solr, solrj, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm writing a custom Solr component which is using a [CloudSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrServer.html) instance to execute an auxilary query on the distributed index. I'm fetching the Zookeeper url and the collection name from the `solrconfig.xml` configuration in the usual way:

```
String zookeeper = params.get(ZOOKEEPER_URL);
String collection = params.get(COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I would like to erase the Zookeeper url entry and the collection name entry from my `solrconfig.xml` file. Is it possible to fetch those values from somewhere else? I'm executing the auxilary query on the same collection that my component is running on. How do I get my collection name and its Zookeeper url from within the component code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zookeeper url and the collection name can be fetched by using the `rb` (`ResponseBuilder`) parameter passed to each of the component's methods:

```
CoreDescriptor coreDescriptor = rb.req.getCore().getCoreDescriptor();

String collectionName = coreDescriptor.getCloudDescriptor().getCollectionName();

ZkController zkController = coreDescriptor.getCoreContainer().getZkController();

String zookeeperUrl = zkController.getZkServerAddress();
```

Assuming the custom component class extends `SearchComponent`, the `rb` parameter is passed to each of the component's public methods: `prepare`, `process`, `distributedProcess`, `modifyRequest`, `handleResponses` and `finishStage`.